# ¿Cómo hacer uso de grid con bootstrap (v3) para formulario?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Quisiera implementar el uso de `Grids` de BS3 en mi Código `html` para evitar el uso de tablas y que mi formulario se viera de la siguiente manera usando grid, esto para mi versión mobile, sin modificar la versión de desktop.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente mi versión de escritorio se esta viendo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es mi código en HTML con el que construyo mi formulario, esta hecho con la ayuda de PHP en una función:

```
public function datosUsuario(){
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<table class="table">';
        echo '<tbody>';
        echo '<tr>                 
            <td class="columna-titulo">No. Empleado:</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Nombre:</td><td class="columna-valor" colspan="2">''</td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>';
        echo '<tr>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Fecha Ingreso:</td><td class="columna-valor" id="TdFechaIngreso">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Antigüedad (Años):</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            <td class="columna-titulo">Departamento:</td><td class="columna-valor">''</td>
            </tr>';                                        
        echo '</tbody>';
        echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';        
    }
```

**Actualización:**

Intente agregando a cada `td` un `.col-sm-12` de la siguiente manera, pero aun no logro obtener el diseño que deseo.

```
public function datosUsuario(){
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<table class="table">';
            echo '<tbody>';
            echo '<tr>                 
                <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">No. Empleado:</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
                <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Nombre:</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12" colspan="2">''</td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>';
            echo '<tr>
                <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Fecha Ingreso:</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12" id="TdFechaIngreso">''</td>
                <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Antigüedad (Años):</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
                <td class="columna-titulo .col-sm-12">Departamento:</td><td class="columna-valor .col-sm-12">''</td>
                </tr>';                                        
            echo '</tbody>';
            echo '</table>';
            echo '</div>';        
        }
```

¿Saben que estoy haciendo mal en mi código?

Comment: la version de BS es 3.X.X avisale a la gente por que ya BS va por la version 4 y 5 (beta)... y no es retrocompatible

Comment: Es correcto, acabo de añadir un enlace a la documentación de la versión que hago uso, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes eliminar la `tabla`, los `tr` y `td`; estos elementos no admiten correctamente el uso de las clases de BS3.

la implementación correcta de Grids para la version 3 de BS es la siguiente:

Pero esto depende del maquetado que quieras realizar; debes entender que puedes combinar columnas (`col`) como tu quieras y que cada `row` es una linea nueva; y que cada breakpoint tiene una nomenclatura `xs`,`sm`,`md`,`lg`; asique debes analizar como quieres tu layout; lamentablemente no tengo tiempo para hacerte el maquetado.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

   
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-success">.col-xs-1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-1 bg-primary">.col-xs-1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-success">.col-xs-8</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-primary">.col-xs-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-primary">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 bg-success">.col-xs-6</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 bg-primary">.col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
    
    <h3>para lo que necesitas, seria algo asi:</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary">.col-xs-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary">.col-xs-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary">.col-xs-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary">.col-xs-8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 bg-success">.col-xs-4</div>
      <div class="col-xs-8 bg-primary">.col-xs-8</div>
    </div>
    
    

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha384-nvAa0+6Qg9clwYCGGPpDQLVpLNn0fRaROjHqs13t4Ggj3Ez50XnGQqc/r8MhnRDZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrias añadir la clase `row` a los `tr` y a los `col-sm-12` quitarles el punto que les precede.

Acabo de probarlo y me sale como tu pides.

Comment: La respuesta estaría mas completa si agregas un ejemplo de lo que propones ;)

Answer (score 0):

tendrías que hacer de los `<tr>` una row para que el la grid de Bootstrap funcione correctamente.
Revisa las comillas de los echo PHP.
No hace falta que coloques el punto dentro de la clase HTML (`.col-sm-12`).
En tamaño md necesitas especificarle el valor para que quede como deseas.
Con la grid de Bootstrap tal vez no haga falta el colspan.
Te dejo el código ejemplo modificado:

```
echo "<div class='container-fluid p-3'>";
echo '<table class="table text-black">';
echo '<tbody>';
echo "<tr class='p-3 row'>".                 
     "<td class='columna-titulo col-sm-12 col-md-3'>No. Empleado:</td><td class='columna-valor col-sm-12 col-md-3'></td>".
     "<td class='columna-titulo col-sm-12 col-md-3'>Nombre:</td><td class='columna-valor col-sm-12 col-md-3'></td>".
     "</tr>";
echo "<tr class='p-3 row'>".
     "<td class='columna-titulo col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Fecha Ingreso:</td><td class='columna-valor col-sm-12 col-md-2' id='TdFechaIngreso'></td>".
     "<td class='columna-titulo col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Antigüedad (Años):</td><td class='columna-valor col-sm-12 col-md-1'></td>".
     "<td class='columna-titulo col-sm-12 col-md-2'>Departamento:</td><td class='columna-valor col-sm-12 col-md-3'></td>".
     "</tr>";                                        
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
```

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: No funciono amigo, puedes validar el uso de comillas, parece ser eso, verifica tu respuesta nuevamente para darle validez.

Comment: no le funciona por que eso es BS4 y el usa BS3

Comment: Es correcto lo que dice @FranciscoNúñez no me funciono por la versión

Comment: Hola, ok, vale, como te lo he mostrado en BS3 no funciona. No conozco alguna manera de hacerlo en esa versión, intenté con media-queries y no funcionó, lo siento.